# Chrome extension only opens last assigned url

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension browser action that I want to have list a series of links, and open any selected link in the current tab. So far what I have is this, using jquery:

```
var url = urlForThisLink;
var li = $('<li/>');
var ahref = $('<a href="#">' + title + '</a>');
ahref.click(function(){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: url});
    });
});
li.append(ahref);
```

It partially works. It does navigate the current tab, but will only navigate to whichever link was last created in this manner. How can I do this for an iterated series of links?

Comment: How are you passing the url into the click event?  I see url: url, but where is that url coming from in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jmort253's answer is actually a good illustration of what is probably your error. Despite being declared inside the `for` loop, `url` has function scope since it is declared with `var`. So your click handler closure is binding to a variable scoped outside the `for` loop, and every instance of the closure uses the same value, ie. the last one.

Once Chrome supports the `let` keyword you will be able to use it instead of `var` and it will work fine since `url` will be scoped to the body of the `for` loop. In the meantime you'll have to create a new scope by creating your closure in a function:

```
function makeClickHandler(url) {
    return function() { ... };
}
```

Inside the `for` loop say:

```
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var url = urls[i]; 
    ...    
    ahref.click(makeClickHandler(url));
    ...
}
```

Comment: After reading the first line, I upvoted the answer. After reading the remainder, I retracted it, because it contains too many errors: 1. Alleging that `url` lies in the global scope without seeing the context of the code is a too specific (possible faulty) statement. I'd be more generic to say that the same `url` variable is shared by all closures of the event handler (not necessarily global; possibly local). 2. `let` is not available by default, and thus invalid syntax.

Comment: 1. Probably the best explanation is that url has function scope. There's no such thing as block scope in JS so the assumption that it will be scoped to the for loop, though logical, is wrong. My bad.

Comment: 2. Again, my bad. I thought Chrome already supported let, but it is officially part of ES6 which I'm told Chrome will support next year. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: BTW: typing code on an iPad is no fun. I'll clean this up a bit when I get to a proper computer. SO needs an iPad app. :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning a closure. I updated my answer to reflect the changes and help the op move forward with a solution. Thanks for mentioning this!

Answer (score 0):

In your code example, it looks like you only have a single link. Instead, let's assume you have an actual collection of links. In that case, you can use a for loop to iterate through them:

```
// collection of urls
var urls = ["http://example.com", "http://domain.org"];

// loop through the collection, for each url, build a separate link.
for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

    // this is the link for iteration i
    var url = urls[i]; 

    var li = $('<li/>');
    var ahref = $('<a href="#">' + title + '</a>');
    ahref.click( (function(pUrl) {
        return function() {
            chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
                chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: pUrl});
            });
        }
    })(url));
    li.append(ahref);
}
```

I totally forgot about scope when writing the original answer, so I updated it to use a closure based on Matthew Gertner's answer. Basically, in the click event handler, I'm now passing in the url variable into an anonymous 1 argument function which returns another function. The returned function uses the argument passed into the anonymous function, so its state is unaffected by the fact that the next iterations of the for loop will change the value of url.